# Python, OpenCV :How to use features extracted via ORB for a classification model?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, data-science

I have a set of a couple thousand images (I'm starting with 40 pictures for a test) and I want to build a classifier that can tell what object is in the picture. Like, is this a picture of my dog, a picture of my neighbors dog or a picture of my brothers dog. I know how to compare two pictures and their keypoints but I'm not sure about using the features extracted in a ML model.

So I started using OpenCV and used ORB to detect 150 keypoints. From what I understand, the descriptor has the information from each keypoint and is what I will use as features. So now I for each image I have 150 features, each feature array of 32. (150,32). I want to put this into a RandomForestClassifer but when I do I get the error >>>>

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

## Here is some of the code:

dogs is the dataframe

```
# Init ORB
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=150)

# Extract descriptors and put them in df
with tqdm(total=len(list(dogs.iterrows()))) as pbar:
    for index, row in dogs.iterrows():
        pbar.update(1)
        im = dogs.at[index, 'filtered']
        kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im,None)
        dogs.at[index, 'kp'] = kp1
        dogs.at[index, 'des'] = des1
os.system('spd-say "Processing complete"')

X = dogs['des']
y = dogs['Id']
features = pd.DataFrame.from_records(X)
features['Id'] = dogs['Id']

X = features.drop('Id',1)
y = features['Id']
```

Looking at first feature of the first image

```
X[1][1]
```

array([  0, 201, 130, 153,  84, 131, 172,  71,  22,   1,  90,   2, 168,
       202,  32,  64, 121,  42,  34, 144,  82, 186,  65, 215,  52,  38,
       154,  64, 149,  10, 176, 136], dtype=uint8)

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

I have never worked with arrays as features in a ML model so it could just be a simple error. If I am going at this totally wrong based on some misunderstanding let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RandomForestClassifier` as well as the majority of conventional ML algorithms can deal only with scalar features. So, in order to use on your data you need to flatten it, e.g. 
`import numpy as np
np.flatten(features.values)`